# What is the difference between foreign_key and primary_key when defining an ActiveRecord association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to understand the difference between `foreign_key` and `primary_key` when defining an association on an ActiveRecord model. Do you need to use both? What is the difference?

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :something_else, foreign_key: 'some_id', primary_key: 'some_id'
end

class SomethingElse < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'some_id'
  belongs_to :some_model, foreign_key: 'some_id', primary_key: 'some_id'
end
```

Answer (score 6):

`primary_key` defines the name of the database field to be used as primary key instead of the default `id`.

`foreign_key` defines the name of the database field which keeps references to the primary key field of another model.

See [Active Record Associations docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key) for more.

If you want conceptual understanding on the role of primary and foreign keys, [here is one writeup](http://www.essentialsql.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-primary-key-and-a-foreign-key/) on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

They are on the opposite sides of the association.

Rails takes value of `foreign_key` and searches model with `class_name` for records with `primary_key` of that value

For example:

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :phone, foreign_key: :this_users_phone_id_field

  has_many :others_with_this_number, ->(user){where.not(id: user.id)},
     class_name:'User',
     foreign_key: :this_users_phone_id_field,
     primary_key: :this_users_phone_id_field
end
```

See more in [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key)